# Can't get DrawImage to work in Java

Tags: java, image, swing, drawimage

```
package chapter4;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;``
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 *
 * @author Ale
 */
public class DrawImage extends JFrame{
    private Image image;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new DrawImage();
    }

    public DrawImage(){
        super("DrawImage");
        setSize(600,600);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Toolkit tk= Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        image= tk.getImage(getURL("yoshi.PNG"));                

    }

    private URL getURL(String filename){
        URL url;
        try{
            url= this.getClass().getResource(filename);
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
        return null;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param g
     */
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2d=(Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);

        g2d.drawImage(image, 20, 40, this);
    }

}
```

The Image is in the same folder as this class , but it gives me errors and doesn't show the image. These are the errors:

```
Uncaught error fetching image:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getConnection(URLImageSource.java:115)
```

and a few more similar. Need help please. The file is a png file of yoshi from mario

Comment: You should avoid overriding `paint` of top level containers like `JFrame`, instead you should use something `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method.  Also make sure that you always call `super.paintXxx` otherwise you could end up with very nasty paint effects. See [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details. Also, you could achieve the same result with a `JLabel` - just saying ;)

Answer (score 3):

You're returning null from your getUrl() method.  You need to return the url object.